# How to check whether a type is directly derived from another type?

Tags: c++, c++17

I know about `std::is_base_of`, but I want to allow just 1 level of inheritance.

```
class A
{
};

class B : public A
{
};

class C : public B
{
};

Is1LevelSubClass<A, C> -> false <- I want this!!!

Is1LevelSubClass<B, C> -> true

std::is_base_of<A, C> -> true

std::is_base_of<B, C> -> true
```

I'm working on MSVC, C++17

Comment: This seems suspect. It shouldn't matter in well-behaved code how long the chain is.

Comment: @Frank I'm making my own Reflection System. I save base class name, type through macros. I just wanna check if correct type name is passed.

Answer (score 1):

Putting aside how misguided this may be, the question as asked can still be answered.

It cannot be done out of the box. If you absolutely need this, you can get there by respecifying the immediate parent as a type member.

```
class A
{
public:
   using derived_from = void;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
   using derived_from = A;
};

class C : public B
{
public:
   using derived_from = B;
};
```

With that, `Is1LevelSubClass<>` is easy to implement:

```
template< class Base, class Derived >
struct Is1LevelSubClass : std::is_same<Base, typename Derived::derived_from> {};

template< class Base, class Derived >
constexpr bool Is1LevelSubClass_v = Is1LevelSubClass::value;
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/zWjzb345c

Comment: Ok, I have system similar to this codes. programmer write using ~, using ~!!. Then I wanna check automatically if correct type is saved to derived_from.

Comment: @SungJinKang If you could determine what the correct type should be automatically, then you wouldn't need to ask the programmer to fill it in. You'd just used the inferred one. The reason the programmer has to write the `using ...` is precisely because you can't automatically know what it should be, otherwise what would be the point?

Comment: I think compiler may know what is parent class. But it never tell me and never let me know how to access it. So I wanna let compiler check type between it knows and programmer write

Comment: @SungJinKang Running checks based on internal compiler state is generally done in a static analyzer, like a custom `clang-tidy` check.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this requires language support for reflection, so it is currently not possible to do this in the standard.

However, you may be able to implement `Is1LevelSubClass` using [`tr2::direct_bases`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/16e2427f50c208dfe07d07f18009969502c25dc8/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/tr2/type_traits) (originally from [N2965](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2965.html)) implemented by gcc.

```
#include <tr2/type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct direct_base { };
template<typename Base>
struct direct_base<std::tr2::__reflection_typelist<Base>> {
  using type = Base;
};
template<class B, class D>
constexpr inline bool Is1LevelSubClass = std::is_same_v<B, 
  typename direct_base<typename std::tr2::direct_bases<D>::type>::type>;
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/KznTr8rK4)